# Sonata Admin Bundle overwrite views

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-sonata

Sonata default use for list index:

```
SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
```

This i use for all modules in Admin. I have modules: Job and Category.
How can i set for module Job for example:

```
SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:listJob.html.twig
```

and for Category:

```
SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:listCategory.html.twig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default list index by adding the mehode in CategoryAdmin and JobAdmin

```
public function  getListTemplate ()
{
    return "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:listJob.html.twig";
}
```